# Use Comma in variable?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there a way to convert this:

```
$('#id').testfunction({
  'source' : [
    {'source':'pathimage.jpg','title':'Title 1','description':'This is a description 1.'},
    {'source':'pathimage.jpg','title':'Title 2','description':'This is a description 2.'},
    {'source':'pathimage.jpg','title':'Title 3','description':'This is a description 3.'},
    {'source':'pathimage.jpg','title':'Title 4','description':'This is a description 4.'},
    {'source':'pathimage.jpg','title':'Title 5','description':'This is a description 5.'}
  ]
});
```

To simple for dynamically output:

```
$('#id').testfunction({
  'source':[
    $SOURCE
  ]
});
```

I am pushing the source into a array and trying to construct it again into `$SOURCE`. The `$SOURCE` should be look like this eventually:

```
$SOURCE = myArray[0], myArray[1], myArray[2], myArray[3], myArray[4];
```

But its the comma thingy that keeps prevent the variable from working. I can't get the comma into the variable. Using `+ "," +` doesnt work since it recognizes it as a string...

```
$SOURCE += myArray[s],;
```

Is there a way to convert this to a working variable to dynamically use?

Comment: Why not: `source: [myArray[0], myArray[1], myArray[2], myArray[3], myArray[4]]` or even `source: myArray`? Maybe if you provide some more information about what you actually want to achieve, we can give more helpful answers. I'm not totally sure what you want to achieve.

Comment: This does seem to be an [XY problem](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=542341).

Comment: its the comma that prevent it from dynamically creation of having it working. when i put all those array manually, it ofcourse just works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, because if `$SOURCE` was an array, then you would be assigning an array to the first element of the `source` parameter; and `$SOURCE` can't represent an array in the way you expect to be able to.

There is no legal construct whereby you can concatenate variables with a comma.

Answer (score 0):

You want to put some values from one array into another one.  This should work but seems kind of daft to me (or you could just loop through myArray, or you could just say `$SOURCE = myArray`):

```
$SOURCE = [];
$SOURCE.push(myArray[0]);
$SOURCE.push(myArray[1]);
$SOURCE.push(myArray[2]); 
$SOURCE.push(myArray[3]); 
$SOURCE.push(myArray[4]);
```

Answer (score -1):

The thing you're looking for is called a [preprocessor macro](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_preprocessor). They don't exist in javascript.